# Flutter не работает карта yandex_mapkit

Tags: android, flutter, yandexmapkit

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Я хочу отобразить карту даже если я не дал разрешение на геолокацию, но в этом случае на android устройстве у меня карта не загружается, вместо этого показывается сетка из квадратов. Логика такая, что если юзер не дал координаты свои, то приложение показывает ему центр Москвы и дальше пусть делает что хочет. Что нужно для этого сделать? На ios устройстве все работает.

У меня пока что нет идей на этот счет.

Answer (score 1):

Ну нашел я косяк свой, когда пытаетесь скрыть api_key, то в MainApplication.kt объявлять вот так =>

```
class MainApplication: Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        var apiKey = getString(R.string.MAP_API_KEY)
        MapKitFactory.setApiKey(apiKey)
    }
}
```

А я делал вот так `MapKitFactory.setApiKey("@string/MAP_API_KEY")`
И у меня вообще карта перестала загружаться, независимо от разрешений на геолокацию, а почему сразу она так не делала я без понятия...